# Unbuffered Multi-line Comments in CoffeeScript?

Tags: syntax, comments, coffeescript, multiline, unbuffered

Correct me if I'm wrong, the only way to have unbuffered (doesn't output to .js) comments in CoffeeScript is

```
# This is the only way to mute this single-line comments
```

The `###` buffers comments for multi-line

```
### This will be outputted to the .js
    For things like copyright notices.
###
```

But there's no way to have unbuffered multi-line comments?

```
# This is the only way to mute
# multiple-lines
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct. But it's less difficult than it looks, because your text editor likely provides a keyboard shortcut for commenting/uncommenting lines. For instance, in TextMate with jashkenas' bundle, you'd just select the lines you want to comment and hit `Cmd+/` to put `#` in front of each. The same shortcut can also un-comment lines in that fashion.

Comment: thanks for answering, lack of multi-line unbuffered commenting stinks.

also i don't think `###` works as well as `#`, i could be wrong though, but `###` sometimes gives me indentation issues or sOmething...